# Qual componente utilizar no PyQt4 para exibir registros de uma consulta SQL na tela?

Tags: python, qt, gui, qtgui, pyqt

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação gráfica para Desktop em Python utilizando o *PyQt4* (Qt Designer), a minha duvida é sobre qual **componente** usar para exibir na minha tela `frmTelaPesqAluno` registros de uma consulta SQL, e como usa-lo? É um componente parecido com o `DataGridView` do Visual Studio ou um *Grid* que eu preciso utilizar para listar os registros da consulta.

Segue imagem da tela que estou desenvolvendo: 
[image: Formulário de pesquisa de Alunos.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procurou na documentação? É a [`QTableWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtablewidget.html). Existem outros *widgets* auxiliares a ele.

Um [exemplo simples em Python](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/10/pyqt4-example-of-tablewidget-usage/).

[Tutorial mais completo para C++ utilizando Model-View](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/modelview.html).

[Outro sobre o assunto](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/model-view-programming.html).

Uma [aplicação completa usando ele](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html).

Comment: Estou em duvida se devo usar um QTableWidget ou QTableView, nunca utilizei um grid no Python.

Comment: A `QTableView` é mais simples e na verdade ela é usada internamente pela `QTableWidget`. Quase sempre você ficará com a mais completa e que permite melhor organização do código. A mais simples não se comparação com a existente no .Net.

Comment: Tem um exemplo do QTableView?

Comment: Tá cheio de exemplos mas não é o que você queria na pergunta: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=qtableview+example

Comment: Eu quero mandar o resultado de uma consulta SQL para o QTableView.

Comment: Aí você tem que fazer outra pergunta mas tem que mostrar o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Vou tentar usar o QTableWidGet a partir do exemplo que vc me passou.